# How does embedding images in an EditText work?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Well I have seen apps like `facebook` and twitter are having an option of adding images in their edit text

so my doubt is weather the edit text has this attribute or they are just using the image view and edit text if so how are they implementing it

I am not asking the back end code of java just the front end using XML
well see in this i can add both image as well as text.

This  is what i meant how do they have both edit text and image as well.

http://postimg.org/image/j7pop69z1/

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with an image of what you mean? I have never seen an example of an EditText implementing ImageViews.

Comment: I am not sure but usually,unless there are really use to use libraries ,I prefer creating my own widgets. So, what i would do to achieve facebook's post editText...I would create my own custom widget that contains a "rebuilt" editText.But first of all, you have to understand how EditText works, so look for documentation on google developer.

Comment: @edwoollard Updated my question with the image link i cant post an image i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Where does the text actually get drawn? I presume it is an EditText that overlays an ImageView.

Comment: thats what i also think bro because as far as i have read the documentation i dont think so it has any option to add images

i think they went with <RelativeLayout><Edittext/><Imageview/></Relativelayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only put text in an Edit Text. You would have to create a Layout and put inside the EditText and an ImageView.

Comment: well yes sir so like you mean to say something like this <linearlayout><edittext /> <imageview /> </linearlayout> am i right sir